# Putting a "Google-Sheets Writer" Java application within a "Basic Gradle Build" into a Docker image/container

Tags: java, docker, gradle, google-sheets

I am new to utilizing Docker.  I have a modified version of Google Sheet's "QuickStart" tutorial Java program within a Gradle Build (It has been modified to write to a few cells rather than reading cells, the Sheet ID has been changed too...the original Quickstart link is here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java ).  The Java program works on its own, but I intend write a Dockerfile that will successfully build an image from the Gradle Build I currently have so it can be run in a container.  Since Dockerfile syntax is nuanced and versatile, and because a Google Sheets Gradle Build has Google dependancies, I'm having trouble figuring out what to do here.  Note that the original application uses a "basic gradle build" (you type "gradle init --type basic" to make it), and the Java code is in a src/main/java directory while the necessary credentials.json file (containing my client ID and secret so Google Sheets will work) is in src/main/resources.  I'm also using Gradle 5.2.1 .
Here is the Java code...

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.UpdateValuesResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SheetsQuickstart {
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

/**
 * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
 * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
 */
private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

/**
 * Creates an authorized Credential object.
 * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
 * @return An authorized Credential object.
 * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
 */
private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
    // Load client secrets.
    InputStream in = SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
    //System.out.println("The getCredentials will be returned");
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
}

//Writes a few basic things to cells in a google sheet



public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    // Build a new authorized API client service.
    final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    final String spreadsheetId = "16WoDySciZRhD3QSH2_V1bk5kf_IFCcrPe49NE8WRxVg";


Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
    .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
    .build();

ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(getData());


UpdateValuesResponse result =
    service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, "B1", body)
            .setValueInputOption("RAW")
            .execute();

}




public static List<List<Object>> getData() {

 List<Object> data1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
 data1.add("test1");
 data1.add("test2");
 data1.add("Row");

 List<Object> data2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
 data2.add("test3");
 data2.add("test4");
 data2.add("test5");

 List<Object> data3 = new ArrayList<Object>();
 data3.add("test6");

 List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
 data.add(data1);
 data.add(data2);
 data.add(data3);

 return data;

 }


 }
```

My build.gradle file looks like this...

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'SheetsQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-sheets:v4-rev516-1.23.0'
}
```

Again, I used a "grovvy basic gradle build" and the directory structure can be found at https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/ near the beginning (also I added the src/main directory in the gradle directory's root).  If I'm to "dockerize" this gradle build, what are my best available options in doing so?  Would it only require one dockerfile, and is there an example of what it might look like?  Are there any things fundamentally wrong with how I am approaching this?   Thanks.